# Is cooked chicken brought to work but left unrefrigerated for 5 hours safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, chicken, refrigerator

I cooked chicken last night and stored it in the fridge right after.

Today I brought in chicken in a glass container within my backpack and opened it 5 hours later. I put it in the microwave for 1 minute and 30 seconds and it still feels a bit cold.

Is it safe to consume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not, as you left it at danger zone temperatures (Between +40F and +140F [4.4C and 60C])  for so long).

What are the odds of food poisoning? You'll need decide

Comment: I never understood how a few hours in a sealed air tight container could do so much. But thanks for the answer

Comment: The bacteria were already there--even in the fridge. The cold just slows down their reproduction. Once the chicken warms up, the bacteria start multiplying again. Heating to over 140 will kill off many of those that have grown.